# how to delete a row in hbase table

Tags: hbase

Does someone know what is the way to remove a row in hbase? In particular, I wanted to delete a row from .META., which might contribute to the very frustrated issue of TableNotFoundException for HBase. I dumped the scan info of '.META.' to a file, which is as follows,

```
scan '.META.'
ROW  COLUMN+CELL
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336311752799, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENCODED => 7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5,}
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020364027, value=master.node:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020364027, value=1337020345458
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336513006700, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENCODED => 8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75,}
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020363795, value=slave-node-1:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020363795, value=1337020346292
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336513006695, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENCODED => 83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08,} tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020363923, value=slave-node-2:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020363923, value=1337020346464
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336383326110, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENCODED => ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b,}
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020363808, value=slave-node-1:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020363808, value=1337020346292
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336383326106, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d,}
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020364031, value=master-node:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020364031, value=1337020345458
 tsdb-uid,,1336081042372.a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336081042581, value={NAME => 'tsdb-uid,,1336081042372.a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa.', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa,}
 tsdb-uid,,1336081042372.a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020363927, value=slave-node-1:60020
 tsdb-uid,,1336081042372.a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020363927, value=1337020346464
6 row(s) in 0.3930 seconds
```

FIrst of all, I dont quite understand why it says there are 6 rows in the results. From my perspective, there are way more rows. I need to get rid of the first three lines from .META.

So I tried this

```
deleteall '.META.', 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5.'
```

hbase shell said 0 rows affected. And yes, the command did not delete any row from .META.

Could anybody shed lights on me what'd be the correct command for deleting a row in this case?

I know it is bad to post two questions in a row, but I have exhausted Google, and cannot find something that could help me on this. Sorry in advance!

Comment: You can also use: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition; if you want to delete a single row.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try truncating the table using the command

truncate 'table-name'.

and start from the beginning.

Comment: This is an option to get rid of the whole table, but my issue really comes from .META. has some loopholes on this table which made this table unaccessible, i.e., I cannot even scan it in the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You have 6 rows as follows:

```
ROW 1: tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336311752799, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENCODED => 7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5,}
     tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020364027, value=master.node:60020
     tsdb,\x00\x00\x0FO\xA2\xF1\xD0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336311752340.7cd0d2205d9ae5fcadf843972ec74ec5. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020364027, value=1337020345458

ROW 2:
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336513006700, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENCODED => 8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75,}
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020363795, value=slave-node-1:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA3\x8C\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.8d66c109dd1446c326050055d3b9cb75. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020363795, value=1337020346292

ROW: 3
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336513006695, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENCODED => 83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08,} tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020363923, value=slave-node-2:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x10O\xA6\xBC \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336513006109.83ff68701e075f0a228247ac44862c08. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020363923, value=1337020346464

ROW: 4
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336383326110, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENCODED => ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b,}
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020363808, value=slave-node-1:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x11O\xA4\xCF\xF0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1D\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.ec0c72f24ff89e1b46a592847db36f4b. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020363808, value=1337020346292

ROW: 5
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336383326106, value={NAME => 'tsdb,\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d.', STARTKEY => '\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d,}
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020364031, value=master-node:60020
 tsdb,\x00\x00\x12O\xA3\xA8\xA0\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x05\x00\x001,1336383325807.d2df62a47e153781932b33480241068d. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020364031, value=1337020345458

ROW: 6
 tsdb-uid,,1336081042372.a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa. column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1336081042581, value={NAME => 'tsdb-uid,,1336081042372.a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa.', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa,}
 tsdb-uid,,1336081042372.a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa. column=info:server, timestamp=1337020363927, value=slave-node-1:60020
 tsdb-uid,,1336081042372.a30d8074431c6a31c6a0a30e61fedefa. column=info:serverstartcode, timestamp=1337020363927, value=1337020346464
```

I'm running v0.94.5 and that seems to have support for a "delete" command.

```
delete 'TABLE_NAME', 'ROW_KEY', 'COLUMN_NAME', TIMETAMP_VALUE_FOR_CELL
```

should do the trick of deleting the entry since you have pointers to all particular cells you wish to delete.

WARNING:
.META. table contains information regarding your region servers and how the table are laid out. You should be very careful when editing this file! I would not recommend modifying this table unless you're very sure that is what you need.

Source: http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/11/16/tip-2-hbase-meta-layout/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't deeply understand HBase, you want to avoid editing the .META. table directly.  From your description, it sounds like you really want to start from scratch, and drop the existing table 'tsdb' and recreate it.  the best way to do that is from the shell:

```
disable 'tsdb'
drop 'tsdb'
```

And then start from the beginning again.

The more general question of how to delete a row is answered fairly well by the HBase book.  You need a table name and a row key.  When you scan a table, you are not getting just the row keys.

Comment: The table cannot be dropped this way since .META. is messed up. I can list this table in the shell, but when I tried to scan this table, HBase said this table does not exist, so diable/drop would not work in this case. Anyway, I deleted the row by writing a java program. The row key is non-ascii, and I guess that is the reason why I cannot delete it in HBase shell.